# Apache: Help disable subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii, dns

I have been handed over an Apache web server 
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) 
running a Yii (1.1.14) website.

The problem is that I can visit w.site.com and ww.site.com and I have no idea where this servername or alias is defined. 
In sites-available the .conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 100.100.200.100:80>
  ServerName site.dk
  ServerAlias www.site.dk
  ServerAlias webmail.site.dk
  ServerAlias admin.site.dk

  DocumentRoot /home/site/apps/site/public_html
  ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/site.dk_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/site.dk_access_log combined
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/site/cgi-bin/
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5

  #Redirect 301 w.site.dk http://www.site.dk
  #Redirect 301 ww.site.dk http://www.site.dk

  <Directory /home/site/apps/site/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/site/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/site/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^w.site.dk [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.dk/$1 [L,R=301]
 </Directory>
 <Directory /home/site/cgi-bin>
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 RewriteEngine on
 #Redirect permanent w.site.dk http://www.site.dk
 #Redirect permanent ww.site.dk http://www.site.dk
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www*).site\.dk [NC]
 #RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.dk/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.site.dk
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.site.dk
 RemoveHandler .php
 RemoveHandler .php5
 php_admin_value engine Off
 IPCCommTimeout 31
 FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
 Alias /blog /home/site/apps/wordpress

 <Directory "/home/site/apps/wordpress">
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/site/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/site/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
  </Directory>

  SuexecUserGroup "#1000" "#1000"
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =webmail.site.dk [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.dk [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.site.dk [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =admin.site.dk
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to redirect w.site and ww.site to www.site as you can see in the commented out Redirect and RewriteCond, but no effort seems to work.

I don't know if it's the .htaccess file then?

./public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://site.dk/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d*)$ /p/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dj-mobil/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dj-(.*)$ /p/dj-$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mobildiskotek-(.*)$ /p/mobildiskotek-$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule . index-test.php

## Forward to Yii
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And if i do a apachectl -S i get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
139.164.505.166:80     site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/0-site.dk.conf:1)
139.164.505.166:443    wmail.site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wmail.site.dk.conf:40)
[2a01:7e20::f03c:96ff:fe27:90ac]:443 wmail.site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wmail.site.dk.conf:40)
 *:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
 default server cloud.site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost cloud.site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
 port 80 namevhost wmail.site.dk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wmail.site.dk.conf:1)
 alias www.wmail.site.dk
 alias webmail.wmail.site.dk
 alias admin.wmail.site.dk
```

I am lost, cannot even redirect away from the strange w. pefixes. Can anyone help with any kind of fix? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first-listed VirtualHost for any set is the "default" for that IP:PORT.  That is what apachectl -S is trying to tell you.

If you want to catch any incoming hostnames that don't match the ones you've explicitly listed off, just define your real stuff in the 2nd vhost (on your debian-like OS, by using the sorting of the sites-available/*.conf)